# which is better saving images in folders with paperclip or using database to save images

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a question in my mind, that is it preferable to keep images in database directly using datatypes like blob,binary etc. or the way paperclip stores images by maintaining folder structure and keeping only the path in database is the standard one.

Comment: This question is going to get a lot of varying responses. Going to get the popcorn ready.

Comment: Use case matters. If nothing special, file system.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.  Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing pictures in the database helps you keeping your data synchronized (what if by any chance a folder name is changed manually?). Then it would save you the small effort to remember to back up data outside the database itself.
On the other side retrieving an image from a database is much slower than doing it from the file system, and database storage space I seem to remember is more expensive on a web server.

Said that, it's just a matter of choice. In case you decide to go for the database, there is a gem helping you to do that '[paperclip_database](https://github.com/softace/paperclip_database)'.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few advantages and disadvantages.

**Advantages**

- Easy to protect the referential integrity. No discrepancy between image (path) saved in DB and the real image saved at the filesystem.
- Database Backup also contains images. But consider you have to backup the application data nevertheless. (So this is not a good argument)
- Easier rights management

**Disadvantages**

- Performance issues. Every image has to be loaded from the database. The more images affected the more weight this argument should get.
- Browser-Cache / Checking if an image has changed (If-modified-Since) not working anymore.
  (But you could implement a checking yourself)

(No complete list)

**My Conclution**

On small sites with less traffic and images it's okay to store images in the database. On bigger sites I wouldn't do that.